# How to lock Orientation for a particular screen in ios in react native?

Tags: react-native, orientation, landscape, landscape-portrait, portrait

I want to lock the orientation of my camera screen.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Camera" component={Camera} options={{ headerShown:false,orientation:'landscape'}}/>
```

This works fine in android but does not work on ios devices.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below plugin for that
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker

Set up plugin and configure as mention in their doc and in react native side add below code which you want to Lock Screen portrait or landscape

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

useEffect(()=>{
   Orientation.lockToPortrait(); //this will lock the view to Portrait
   Orientation.lockToLandscape(); //this will lock the view to Landscape
})
```

**EDIT**

One more plugin is there you can set screen wise orientation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation
In my one of the project this is also working . Hope your issue will be resolve on this.

Comment: @KaushalLalani You set up all steps for iOS ? Because without configure all steps in Xcode it will not work so follow document steps

Comment: Yes I have followed every steps which where given in the package but still it is not working is there any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: Yes then try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation In past project I used this one also and it is working both OS android and iOS, Hope this will resolved your problem